# How to test VM monitoring in vmware ESXi?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I would really like to test VM monitoring, so if the VM locks up, vmware will restart it. I set the high sensitivity for VM monitoring for one particular virtual machine. I tried to:

1) Turn off vmware tools with /etc/init.d/...
2) Kill the vmware tools process
3) Run a fork bomb

The restart of the VM was not initiated at all. In the summary tab I have Vmware tools not running, but no action is made. Why? (it's vmware esxi with vcenter)

Comment: BSOD the windows VM does not work too. I will contact vmware support maybe.

Comment: what version are you running?

Comment: It is 4.1, the right answer is below.

Answer (score 2):

I discussed the problem with vmware, and we spent a lot of time for gathering logs and analysing them. Actually, they told me I found a bug in vCenter. When you set VM Monitoring specific setting for the VM to High, the VM Monitoring will be not configured at all. You have to set it to Use Cluster Setting, then Ok, then open the Vmware HA options again and choose High. Now VM Monitoring works like a charm. I hope it will be fixed, I cannot believe I was the only one with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is/are all the VMware Hosts configured for HA ?

NOTE that any manual actions will not trigger the Monitor - stopping the VM or editing the VM settings has no effect on this, since it is assumed that you wanted to do that.

Answer (score 0):

you wanted to test VM monitoring? 
VM tools is used by VMware ESX for heartbeat messages to each of the monitored VMs

so the options #1 and 2 from the above are not good ideas.